# How do I run autocomplete directly from the server instead of the default JQuery UI autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am currently using the Jquery UI bundle to fill in the Autocomplete search parameters in an input HTML box.

### html file:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   var userfirstnameTags = [ "John",  "Katy",  "Will",  "Shrek", ];
   var userlastnameTags = [ "Snow",  "Perry",  "Smith",  "Rooney", ];
   $( "#user_first_name" ).autocomplete({
   source: userfirstnameTags
   });  
});
</script>
```

---

The issue right now is that all the username and other sensitive data that I have appears on the html/js file on the front end code.

I would like to protect this information + i do not want the code to load all user data every time it loads the search page.

Is there an alternate way to use this autocomplete/ to index autocomplete directly from the server-side? I am using Ruby on Rails for my server side.

Comment: use ajax to pull data from server side and then bind it up with userfirstnameTags and userlastnameTags ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077409/jquery-ui-autocomplete-server-side-example-what-does-a-request-json-response-lo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery auto-completer gives you the option to load the data from server. Checkout this link
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote