# Array format for autocomplete JQuery with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to change source data of my autocomplete JQuery but i can't understand what kind of array i have to send in PHP at my JS function because i use this to change source data :

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete('option', 'source', tab);
```

and i send this result to my JS function :

```
{"transport":{"voiture":"voiture","car":"car","avion":"avion"}}
```

my php for this result :

```
foreach ($result as $k => $v)  {        
    //Stockage des valeurs dans un tableau associatif 
        $listtransport[$v['transport']] = $v['transport'];
    }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077409/jquery-ui-autocomplete-server-side-example-what-does-a-request-json-response-lo

Comment: What exactly does `$result` look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is the JSON accepted by the JqueryUI Autocomplete

```
[
    { 
      id:    elementId, 
      label: label,
      value: value to set when the element is selected
    },
    //Write other elements
]
```

You could build this array in the follow manner

```
$ayValues = array();

foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
    $ayValues[] = array(
        'id' => $v['transport']['id index'],         //This is the id of the value
        'label' => $v['transport']['label index'],   //This is the label show
        'value' => $v['transport']['value index']    //This is the value setted
    );
}

print json_encode($ayValues);
```

Without the content of **$result** it's impossible to write a clear response.

You could omit the id key