# Parse.com Autocomplete search bar javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, autocomplete

I wonder if there is any possibility to make a dynamic search bar with autocomplete in a parse.com javascript app.

Generaly i know that in jquery the autocomplete with tags is something like this

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });


<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

So i have a class in parse.com and a column inside that there is the name as a string, although i have the same testing word now, after some days it will be with different names etc.

[image]

So the question is, is there any way to take all the names (strings) of the "magazia" class and put them as the availableTags on the above example of search???
I mean, instead of having this array of manual strings, to have the strings of the names of my class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21385958/4028085

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5079268/4028085

Comment: @brso05 i can make the autocomplete with the available tags that i put manually, but i want instead of manual strings, to put the names of my parse class.